# How to use shoulda-matchers with Minitest Specs style in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, shoulda

The [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) documentation for Minitest usage provide an example for how to use them in the assertion style, like so:

```
class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  should validate_presence_of(:name)
end
```

**But how do I use them using the Minitest's Spec style?**

The following produces the error: `Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method 'validate_presence_of'`

```
describe Person do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

Comment: You may check this:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/wiki/Usage-with-standard-MiniTest-tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually quite similar to the original way. For one of my personal projects, this is what my `VideoTest` class looks like, and I've been using MiniTest Spec.

```
require 'test_helper'

describe VideoTest do
  let(:video) { build :video }

  should belong_to :course

  should validate_presence_of :title
  should validate_presence_of :description
end
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. This is correct. I was pretty sure I did it that way originally and it wasn't working, but I tried it again and it's working. Your answer helped validate that it should work. Thanks!